# Election tab in events (on sidebar) shows wrong amount of time remaining

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

Both on Meta and on the main site, it shows the wrong amount of time remaining for the election:

[image]

In reality, the election ends in over a week (May 29th)

This was likely caused by the extension of the nomination phase, they must've forgot to update the time for the "event".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the event is generated automatically... extending the nomination period did not alter the event though. I've fixed the end date:

> [image]